# Maximum number of linearly independent solutions of nonhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $p(x),q(x),r(x)$ are continuous functions on some interval such that $r(x)\neq 0$. How one can prove that the non-homogeneous differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x)$ has exactly two linearly independent solutions? And in general, how do you prove that the maximum number of linearly independent solutions of a differential equation $y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+\dots + p_1 y'+p_0 y=r(x)$ with continuous coefficients is $n$? I know that in case of a **homogeneous** differential equation this is true (the solutions form a vector space), but I've never seen a similar statement for non-homogeneous equations.

Comment: This seems wrong. Inhomogeneous equations have an affine space as solution space. Only homogeneous equations have a sub-vector space as solution space where you can speak of basis and generating systems.

Comment: @LutzL - so can you give an example of a second order non-homogeneous differential equation that has three linearly independent solutions? Thank you.

Comment: This is still the wrong question. Of course the vector space of translations (=homogeneous solution space) has dimension 2. But you will need 3 points to span the affine space as $c_1y_1+c_2y_2+c_3y_3$ where $c_1+c_2+c_3=1$.

Comment: Why wrong? It is a pretty simple question. Can I find three linearly independent functions $y_1 (x), y_2(x), y_3(x)$ such that all solve the equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x)$? From your answer I understand that the answer is yes provided certain conditions are fulfilled. I'm not familiar with affine space though.

Comment: Yes, any three solutions in general position will be linearly independent. And more, the vectors $(y_j(x),y_j'(x),y_j''(x))$, $j=1,2,3$, will be linearly independent in any point $x$ where $r(x)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A line is determined by 2 points, a (2D) plane needs 3 points to fix it in higher-dimensional space etc.

Which means in general that an affine space of dimension $n$ is determined only by $n+1$ points $y_0,y_1,...,y_n$ and all other points are affine combinations
$$
y=c_0y_0+c_1y_1...+c_ny_n\quad\text{ where }\quad c_0+c_1+...+c_n=1
$$
One can eliminate $c_0$ and the coefficient condition via
$$
y=y_0+c_1(y_1-y_0)+...+c_n(y_n-y_0)
$$
where you find again the usual form of particular solution plus general homogeneous solution with $n$ free parameters.

---

The $n+1$ inhomogeneous solutions $y_0,y_1,...,y_n$ are in general position, i.e., actually span the full affine inhomogenous solutions space if and only if the homogenous solutions $(y_1-y_0),...,(y_n-y_0)$ are a basis of the homogeneous solution space (which you stated you already know about).